# Angular 2 Router.navigate in Service. Good Practice?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am building an application where there are many user roles. So when I login and I get the user role back in the response and have to navigate accordingly. I have made a service url-redirect.service.ts and in that I have made a function like this.

```
redirect(user_role){ 

switch (user_role){
case 1: this.router.navigate[route1];
         break;
case 2: this.router.navigate[route2];
         break;

}
```

Like that.

But the thing is in login.component.ts after I delegate that thing to service. I have some code to execute like this:

```
this.urlService.redirect(res.data[0].user_roles);

setCookies();

setLanguage();

and so on;
```

so it works fine now. But I just have that gut feeling that it is not right thing to do as there is some code after that and route gets changed in between that. I am not sure what are the pros and cons. Can somebody let me know, if that is the good practice?

Answer (score 0):

I pondered the same issue. Here's my service login method:

```
login(credentials: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.endpoint + '/login', credentials)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .do((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      console.warn('on successful login => navigate to redirectUrl');
      this.router.navigate([this.getRedirectUrl()]);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.user = null;
      return this.handleError(err);
    });
}
```

You can see I make a call to .do()

This allows you to do something (on a successful response) but ensures that your method returns an Observable (which you can subscribe to in the calling code).

I did a navigate inside .do() BECAUSE a successful login will ALWAYS navigate to the currently set redirect URL.

If it did not ALWAYS do this then `router.navigate` would be wrong. However, given that it ALWAYS does this then this approach ensures consistency.